# Java synchronized vs stricter DB isolation level?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot web service with some method that does a get-from-DB followed by insert-if-not-present (with some logic in between that I'd rather keep in Java for now).
The method is annotated with @Transactional, but of course with the default isolation level (read committed), it's possible to end up with the same row inserted twice if two run in parallel.
If I change isolation level to serializable, then I would get a performance hit.
Would it be better to use plain Java synchronized, and to synchronize on a global object that uniquely represents the item being queried/added? Basically I would intern the string param that gets passed to the method, which represents some item name, and synchronize against that.
Obviously I wouldn't be able to scale horizontally, but let's assume this instance of the web service is the only client of the DB.

Comment: I would do none of the above. Simply insert, and if the insertion fails due to a unique constraint violation, then you know the row has already been inserted.

Comment: @JBNizet I had the same idea before I read you comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add unique constraint for inserted data. This way you will be not able to insert the same data twice.

Comment: That's the only sensible solution

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that the  Web Service is the only client and that only one instance is running than Synchronized will do the work perfectly but it's not a good practices and you better do Strict Db isolation even implement coherence checks and contraint at DB Level